# Trying to implement setPublickeyAuthenticator in Java for ssh connection and test it

Tags: java, sshd

I'm new to `java` and `sshd`. Now I'm trying to use the Apache mina `sshd` to implement the public key authenticate for ssh connection.
After checking the library, I found the `setPublickeyAuthenticator` interface. After checking the description, the interface `setPublickeyAuthenticator` does not perform a security handshake using public and private keys. What it does is determine if a particular user is allowed on the server based on his public key.

**Question 1:** I want to confirm whether in the `setPublickeyAuthenticator#authenticate` function, we could only compare the `PublicKey` key in parameters with the public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, right?

**Question 2:** After checking, there may be several key format, the `RSAPublicKey` format `Begin Public Key ... End Public Key`, the `ssh2` public key format `Begin SSH2 Public Key ... End SSH2 Public Key`, the `open-ssh` key `ssh-rsa ...`. The `authorized_keys` is the `open-ssh` format, what about the parameter Public key format in `setPublickeyAuthenticator#authenticate(Public key)`?

**Question 3:** If **Question 1** is yes, how to call the `setPublickeyAuthenticator#authenticate` to make the authentication is called?  How to test it become effective?

**Question 4:** The `UserAuthPublicKey#doAuth` function performs a security handshake using public and private keys, seems the implementation is enough and we don’t need to overwrite it again, we only need to modify the `setPublickeyAuthenticator#authenticate`, right?

**Question 5:** `sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(new File(sshDir, "key.ser")));` I really don't know what's the meaning of the function and how is it used?

Now my code is below:

```
public class SSHServer {
protected SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();

public SSHServer(int port, final Device device) throws Exception {

    sshd.setPort(port);

    List<NamedFactory<Command>> ssFactories = new ArrayList<NamedFactory<Command>>();

    sshd.setSubsystemFactories(ssFactories);

    sshd.setCommandFactory(new CommandFactory());

    sshd.setShellFactory(new Factory<Command>()); 

    this.setup();
}

public void setup() {        
    String sshDir = ".ssh";        
    authorizedKeysFile = new File(sshDir, ".ssh/authorized_keys");      

    //private key file
    sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(new File(sshDir, "key.ser")));


    sshd.setPublickeyAuthenticator(new PublickeyAuthenticator() {            
        public boolean authenticate(String username, PublicKey key, ServerSession session) {
            //the parameter key is the openssh key type
            String s1 = "";
            if(key instanceof RSAPublicKey) {
                  s1 = new String(encode((RSAPublicKey)key));

            }

            String s2 = new 
            String(Base64.decodeBase64(knownKey.getBytes()));//ssh2 public key type
            return s1.equals(s2);
        }


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SSHServer server = new SSHServer(2222, dev);
    server.start();
    System.out.println("Press enter to quit");
    System.in.read();
    server.stop();
}
```

Comment: It seems you have too many questions, it is better to ask questions in different posts and try to simplify your questions, this way you can have people answer your questions

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! OK, I will seperate these questions in different posts.